I need help to solve $2^{1+2\cos(6x)} + 16^{\sin^2 x}=9$
High school student here, there is a trig equation I am trying to solve that involves exponents.
The equation is:$$2^{1+2\cos(6x)} + 16^{\sin^2 x}=9.$$
I have solved a similar problem before by substituting the two numbers that have exponents with a variable and then solving it as a quadratic.
I tried the same idea here:
$2^{1+2\cos6 x} + 2^{4\sin^2 x} = 9$
$2^{1+2\cos6 x} + 2^{4-4\cos^2 x} = 9$
And from here I am not sure how to further break them down to make substituting  possible.
I have tried breaking down the $2\cos 6x$ using the formula for $\cos 3x$ and then $\cos 2x$ but it seems to lead to a dead end.
$ 2\cos 6x = 2(4\cos^3 2x - 3\cos 2x)$
$= 2(4(8\cos^6 x - 6\cos^4 x + 6\cos^2 x - 1) - 3(2\cos^2 - 1))$
Tried factoring but got nowhere.
Another thing I have tried was using $\sin^2 x = \frac{1-\cos 2x}{2}$, this is where I got:
$2^{1+2\cos 6x} + 2^{2-2\cos 2x} = 9$
Could not proceed any further.
I also fiddled with it long enough to notice that this problem would be straightforward if it was $\sin^2 3x$ instead of just $\sin^2 x$, so maybe it was a mistake in writing?
Any help is appreciated!

For what it's worth, virtually every MathSE posted question that I have seen, that followed this article on MathSE protocol has been upvoted rather than downvoted.  I am not necessarily advocating this protocol.  Instead, I am merely stating a fact: if you scrupulously follow the linked article, skipping/omitting nothing, you virtually guarantee a positive response.

Re my last comment, if you read the protocol article carefully, you will see that part of its intent is for the OP (i.e. original poster) to try to discern the intent of the problem composer.  This explains the focus on tools.

Maybe the best that could be done is to prove that $2$ values exist for $\cos x$ ?

Do you have any reason to expect there would be a closed form solution for this equation?

well i suppose if the equation comes from a high-school textbook, it would make sense

As it has been mentioned, it is perhaps impossible to find a closed form for two of the three periodic solutions. However we can use the function graph to compute approximate solutions.
Firstly, we need to simplify the initial equation:$$
2^{1+2cos(6x)}+16^{sin^2{(x)}}=9\\
2^{1+2cos(6x)}+2^{4sin^2{(x)}}=9
$$Then we proceed to simplify the exponents via the trigonometric identities:$$1+2cos(6x)=1+2(4cos^{3}(2x)-3cos(2x))=8cos^{3}(2x)-6cos(2x)+1
\\4sin^{2}=4\left(\frac{1-cos(2x)}{2}\right)=2-2cos(2x)$$
In order to plot the graph we will substitute $cos(2x)$ for $u$, so we get:
$$2^{8u^{3}-6u+1}+2^{2-2u}=9$$
The function graph of $y = 2^{8u^{3}-6u+1}+2^{2-2u}$ is the following (using Desmos):

The function graph intersects the line $y = 9 $ in two points $(1, 9)$ and $(a, 9)$, $a\approx-0.1695419$. So the solutions for $u$ are $u_{1} = 1, u_{2} = a$. After substitution we get: $$cos(2x) = 1\\x_{1} = \pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}\\$$$$
cos(2x) = a\\
2x = arccos(a) + 2 \pi k \\
x_{2} = \frac{arccos(a)}{2} + \pi k, k\in\mathbb{Z}\\$$$$
2x = 2 \pi - arccos(a) + 2 \pi k \\
x_{3} = -\frac{arccos(a)}{2} + \pi(k+1), k\in\mathbb{Z}
$$
If we take $arccos(a) \approx 1.741161148$, the results are $
x_{2} = 0.870580574 + \pi k, x_{3} = 2.27101208 + \pi (k+1)$, where $k \in \mathbb{Z} $. So the set of all possible solutions is $$\bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\{\pi k, 0.870580574 + \pi k, 2.27101208 + \pi (k+1)\} $$
Furthermore, the graph of the initial periodic function $y = 2^{1+2cos(6x)}+16^{sin^{2}(x)}$ looks like this (Desmos):

This answer is more or less a summary of what has been said in the comments. Unless someone discovers the closed form for $a$, I suppose this is the only way to solve this. I also think it's quite likely that this problem has a typo as you suggested.

COMMENT.- An undeniable fact is that the fonction is periodical and that if we take the approximation $a=0.870580584370792$ and $b=2.27101206921900$, there are three solutions in each period, the half-open interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$  which are
$$(x_1,x_2,x_3)=(n\pi, a+n\pi,b+n\pi)\text{ where } n\in\mathbb Z$$ All this it is deduced from plotting $$2\times2^{2\cos(6x)}+2^{4\sin^2(x)}=9$$ The difficulty of this problem is to deduce this answer without the function graph. It is maybe impossible to find out a closed form for $a$ and $b$. Anyway for each integer $n$ the solutions are roots of
$$x^3-(a+b+3n\pi)x^2+(ab+3n^2\pi^2+2n(a+b)\pi)x-(n^3\pi^3+n^2(a+b)\pi^2+nab\pi)=0$$ which are in the half-open interval $[n\pi,(n+1)\pi)$. But what about $a$ and $b$?

This is not a full answer, but a suggestion to tackle the proposed exercise instead.
According to the trigonometric identities, one gets the following relation:
\begin{align*}
\cos(6x) & = 1 - 2\sin^{2}(3x)\\
& = 1 - 2(3\sin(x) - 4\sin^{3}(x))^{2}\\
& = 1 - 2(9\sin^{2}(x) - 24\sin^{4}(x) + 16\sin^{6}(x))\\
& = 1 + 48\sin^{4}(x) - 18\sin^{2}(x) - 32\sin^{6}(x)
\end{align*}
Hence, if we make the change of variable $u = \sin^{2}(x)$, one gets the following equation:
\begin{align*}
2^{1 + 2\cos(6x)} + 16^{\sin^{2}(x)} = 9 & \Longleftrightarrow 2^{3 + 96u^{2} - 36u - 64u^{3}} + 2^{4u} = 9
\end{align*}
I do not think the proposed equation can become any neater than this.
Hopefully this helps!

If we consider, as  @Piquito wrote it, that we look for the zero's of function
$$f(x)=2\times2^{2\cos(6x)}+2^{4\sin^2(x)}-9$$ by inspection or graphing, beside the trivial $n\pi$, $x_n=(2n+1)\frac \pi 4$ seems to be a good approximation.
Expanding the function as a Taylor series around the first root
$$f(x)= -3+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\,\left(x-\frac{\pi }{4}\right)^n$$ where, with $L=\log(2)$, the first coefficients are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 n & a_n \\
 1 & 40 L \\
 2 & 176 L^2 \\
 3 & \frac{464}{3} L \left(4 L^2-1\right) \\
 4 & \frac{5312}{3} L^2\left(L^2-1\right) \\
\end{array}
\right)$$
Using only the above terms and power series reversion
$$x_1=\frac \pi 4+\frac{895188 L^2+5445}{16000000 L^3}=0.867138$$ while the "exact" solution is $0.870581$.
Using $8$ terms, it would be $0.870247$.
This gives the $(a,b)$ terms.
